# Segmentation fault occurs when debugging

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a code below. The idea is to find the frequencies of an array of numbers, then add it into the results vector.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<unordered_map>

using namespace std ;

vector<int> topKFrequent(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
    vector<vector<int>> listCountFrequent(nums.size());
    unordered_map<int,int> mapCountFrequent ;
    vector<int> results ;

    // Đếm tần suất
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
    {
        if(mapCountFrequent.find(nums[i]) == mapCountFrequent.end()) mapCountFrequent.insert({nums[i],1}) ;
        else 
        {
            ++mapCountFrequent[nums[i]] ;
            vector<int>::iterator delete_ = nums.begin() + i ;
            nums.erase(delete_) ;
            --i ;
        }
    }

    // Insert tần suất vào vector
    for (int i : nums)
    {
        int x = mapCountFrequent[(i)] ;
        listCountFrequent[x].push_back(i) ;
    }

    // Xuất ra
    for (int i = listCountFrequent.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(listCountFrequent[i].size() != 0)
            for (int j = listCountFrequent[i].size() - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                results.push_back(listCountFrequent[i][j]) ; 
                
                if( --k <= 0) break;
            }
        if( k <= 0) break;
    }

    return results ;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> nums = {1};
    int k = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < topKFrequent(nums,k).size(); i++)
    {
        cout << topKFrequent(nums,k)[i] << " " ;
    }
}
```

The error is `Segmentation fault` at line 26 to 30 when I am debugging the program. Can you help me to fix this problem?

Comment: *"at line 26 to 30"* -- how many of the other lines can you get rid of while keeping the crash? The more focused a [mre] (while still being reproducible) the better.

Comment: It strikes me as suspect that you are looping based on `nums.size` but within the loop you're _modifying_ `nums`.

Comment: Also that you are recalculating `topKFrequent(nums,k)` on each loop iteration in `main`. This becomes especially problematic when `topKFrequent` is apparently modifying `nums`.

Comment: In `main()` every time `topKFrequent(nums,k)` is called, a new `vector` is returned, and `nums` and `k` are modified. So, you are looping over the `size()` of one `vector`, but then printing an element from a different `vector`. You probably meant to call `topKFrequent()` once and then loop over its result.

Comment: Since `i` is the variable being used to control the loop, it is pretty suspicious that `i` is *modified* in the loop.    Such an approach is okay sometimes, but it's also easy to suddenly have an array index out of bounds - but the loop continues as if the index is in bounds.

Comment: @Peter if you are referring to `i` in the 1st `for` loop of `topKFrequent()`, the `--i` is necessary to avoid skipping elements in `num`, and it will not go out of bounds. However, the `i` in the loop of `main()` can easily go out of bounds

Comment: I think I've found why you got yourself into this mess:  `vector<int> topKFrequent(vector<int>& nums, int k)` -- Change that to `vector<int> topKFrequent(const vector<int>& nums, int k)` -- Now you are forced to *not* change the input vector.   Once this is done, rewrite your function.  Also, a function named like `topKFrequent` shouldn't be messing up the input that I give it.  It should simply return to me the topK frequent items.